# Could someone explain the "scp" bash command for ftping files?

Tags: bash, ftp, scp

I've been trying to learn how to ftp through the command line.

I've tried these but am having some minor issues:

```
$ cd path/to/parent/of/local_directory
$ scp -r local_directory username@74.212.212.222:/absolute/path/to/remote_directory
```

This seems to get the files up there, but it's dumping the `local_directory` into the `remote_directory`.

ie:

```
$ ssh username@domain.com    // assuming you signed it alright
$ cd path/to/remote_directory
$ ls
./ ../ index.html local_directory
```

I don't want to dump the directory in there, I want to update the files & directories inside the `remote_directory`.  **How do I get this to work correctly?** I believe it has something to do with the `/'s` after the directory names but I'm not quite sure which should go where.

Comment: *"I've been trying to learn how to ftp through the command line."* `scp` != FTP.

Comment: `scp` stands for `Secure Copy`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes but isn't `scp` a plausible alternative?  Or should I try to stick with FTP?

Comment: @AlexCory: Not just plausible, an *excellent* alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're telling it to copy the directory. If you just want to copy the files, add `/*` to the source param:

```
scp -r local_directory/* username@74.212.212.222:/absolute/path/to/remote_directory
# Here ---------------^^
```

Answer (score 3):

With that you are copying the folder, what you need to copy are the folder contents, have you tried this?

```
scp -r local_directory/* username@74.212.212.222:/absolute/path/to/remote_directory
```

Answer (score 1):

`scp` works like the `cp` command. The correct `scp` command would be :

```
scp -r local_directory/* username@74.212.212.222:/absolute/path/to/remote_directory
```

This copies the `local_directory` content into the `/absolute/path/to/remote_directory`